# Why don't we just say that the Klein Gordon equation describes a two component complex function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, antimatter, klein-gordon-equation

These vectors form the basis vectors of the field that the KG equation describes: (for each $\vec{p}$ in $R^3$):

$$|e^{i\vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}} , E=+\sqrt {p^2+m^2}\rangle$$

$$|e^{i\vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}} , E=-\sqrt {p^2+m^2}\rangle$$

Clearly, **any** single component function $\psi (x)$ can be expressed as a linear combination of only *half* of these basis vectors.

If we utilise **all** of these basis vectors in a linear combination, we will end up describing a **two component function ($\psi _1 (x), \psi _2 (x)$), not one!**

The energy $E$ serves as a label to double the number of basis vectors!! This equation isn't about a single component function.

**To put it another way**, given a single component initial state $\psi (x)$, you will never know how to evolve it in time using the KG equation! This is because there will be ambiguity about whether to attach $e^{-iEt}$ or $e^{+iEt}$ in the evolution, because each momentum eigenstate is degenerate. This ambiguity goes away with the two component KG equation:

$$\frac {d \psi _1 (x)}{dt}= +\sqrt {P^2+m^2} \psi _1 (x)$$

$$\frac {d \psi _2 (x)}{dt}= -\sqrt {P^2+m^2} \psi _2 (x)$$

Comment: Please don't yell at us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem confused about what's going on because you do not clearly distinguish between spatial $\vec x$ and total 4-position $x$.

It is *true* that any function $f(\vec x)$ can be expressed as a "superposition" of either $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\vec p\cdot \vec x}$ or its conjugate - that's just the Fourier transform.

It is *false* that this has anything to do with the Klein-Gordon equation - solutions to the KG equation are functions $f(x)$ on spacetime, and you cannot express such a function as a superposition of $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\vec p\cdot \vec x}$s. You *could* do a 4d Fourier transform and express arbitrary functions on spacetime as "superpositions" of $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} p\cdot x}$, but note that in this case $p^0$ would be *wholly independent* from the other components of momentum, since the Fourier transform doesn't know anything about the mass shell.

Instead, the claim about the solution to the Klein-Gordon equation is the following: Any solution $f(x)$ can be expressed as
$$ f(x) = \int \left(A(\vec p)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\vec x\cdot \vec p - tE_p)} + B(\vec p)\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}(\vec x\cdot \vec p - tE_p)}\right)\frac{1}{2 E_p}\frac{\mathrm{d}^3p}{(2\pi)^3}$$
for arbitrary functions $A(\vec p)$ and $B(\vec p)$. Here we have written the exponentials explicitly in terms of $E_p$, since the shorthand $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}px}$ seems to be core to the confusion in the question.

This is *not a Fourier transform*, it really is superposing the specific "basic" solutions $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\vec x\cdot \vec p - tE_p)}$ and $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}(\vec x\cdot \vec p - tE_p)}$, and there are *lots* of functions $f(x)$ that cannot be expressed in this form - if a function has this form, then it is a solution to the Klein-Gordon equation. Additionally, both summands are needed - there is no way to claim we would only need "half" of this.

---

As for turning the Klein-Gordon equation into a first-order equation:

Your "two-component" solution at the end doesn't really make a lot of sense - what is "$\sqrt{P^2+m^2}$" supposed to be, after all? For an arbitrary function $\psi(x)$, there is no such thing as "$P^2$" - all you can take there is the differential operator $\partial_i\partial^i$, and what even is the square root of a differential operator? You can try to make this work but it's really not something that would be computationally tractable even if you manage to make it well-defined.

Nevertheless, this line of thought ("how do I turn the KG equation into a first-order equation?") is precisely what [led Dirac to the Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Dirac%27s_coup). It turns out that in order to have an operator that squares nicely to the KG equation in every component, you need to have *four* components, not just two, but otherwise, that's exactly what Dirac did - every solution of the Dirac equation (where $\psi$ is a 4-component object whose components are *coupled* through this equation via the action of the [$\gamma$-matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices))
$$ (\mathrm{i}\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu - m) \psi(x) = 0$$
also has the property that every component of $\psi(x)$ individually fulfills the KG equation.

Comment: But I was trying to describe the KG field at paused time, i.e. the Schrodinger-like wave function associated with it. My point was that, if we take the KG equation to be describing the time evolution of an initial state, the initial state MUST be having two components. The two component KG equation that I wrote in the end is even unitary! No negative probabilities anymore!

Comment: @RyderRude I do not know what you mean by the "KG field at paused time". The notion of a solution to the KG equation only makes sense for functions $f(x)$, it does not make sense to claim that some $f(\vec x)$ is a solution. Note also that your "square root" equations are essentially what the Dirac equation is.

Comment: You are right. I'm wording my thoughts in the wrong away. I'll express it as an analogy with the free Schrodinger equation. There, the energy eigenstates are $|e^{ipx} , E= \frac{p^2}{2m}\rangle $. So there's one $E$ for each $\vec{p}$. However, in KG, there are two $E's$ for each $\vec{p}$. The energy eigenstates are $|e^{ipx}, +- \sqrt {p^2+m^2}\rangle$. The linear combinations of these eigenstates result in a two component function.

Comment: My square root KG equation doesn't describe spinors though. It describes a scalar field of two components.

Comment: @RyderRude You're not making a lot of sense to me. In order to find "energy eigenstates", you would have to have a *Hamiltonian*. The solutions to the KG equation are not "energy eigenstates", it's just a (classical) relativistic wave equation! The Hamiltonian formulation of the KG equation is actually a bit subtle because its reparametrization invariance means the naive Hamiltonian is zero, and so in order to first-quantize it in the usual fashion you need to look into quantization of constrained Hamiltonian systems.

Comment: But classical relativistic wave equations can have eigenfunctions, at least in the mathematical sense. The Dirac equation has them! (if you re-write it as a Schrodinger-like equation).  I did write the Hamiltonian of KG at the end of the post. I just made the square into a square root, and that naturally results in two components. And the two component equation I got doesn't describe a spinor, but a scalar!

Comment: The Hamiltonian is the diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $\sqrt {P^2+m^2}$ and $-\sqrt {P^2+m^2}$

Comment: I will try to quantise this two component field. I think we'll get a nice QFT out of this

Comment: @RyderRude No, that's not how Hamiltonians work - the KG equation comes from an action principle with a Lagrangian - the Hamiltonian is the Legendre transform of this Lagrangian, not some random square root you just happen to like. I've edited the answer with a discussion of the Dirac equation - you're really just repeating the "hopeless" attempts at "fixing" the KG equation here that people tried before Dirac came up with his solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135375/discussion-between-ryder-rude-and-acuriousmind).